# В проекте перестали работать ImageView и ImageButton

Tags: android, imageview

Не знаю, почему так, но эти два элемента перестали отображаться в приложении. Причем на предпросмотре они есть. В случае с кнопкой, там просто не показывается выбранное изображение. А обычное imageview вообще не показывается. Все элементы видимые, картинки и свои, и стандартные, и растровые и векторные пробовал. Показывается только на предпросмотре. И новые экраны создавал, ничего не помогает. Видимо какой-то апдейт накатился или несоответствие в версиях инструментов? Или что? Кто сталкивался, куда потыкать? 
Все остальные элементы, до которых дошли руки, работают

UPD
Удалось вывести растровое изображение. Добавил ImageView путем перетаскивания на экран во вкладке Design, ручками заменил app:srcCompat на android:src. Не понимаю, почему так. Вектор, кстати, тоже стал отображаться. Мне кажется, или это странно? Студия сама же ругается на это. Кто может прояснить ситуацию? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: visible не проставили случайно gone?

Comment: Покажите разметку проблемных вьюх

Comment: @TimurVI да с этим тоже всяко разно баловался, не в этом дело

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Обновил пост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app:srcCompat` для указания картинки для отображения какая-то устаревшая фича-костыль для старых версий SDK. Надо везде использовать обычный `android:src`. Студия может на него ругаться по причине старых версий библиотек поддержки и прочих особенностей сборки.